# How to send GET request by Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use github oauth. I'n using urllib and urllib2 and have this code:

```
def github_login(request):
     post_data = [('client_id','****'),('redirect_uri','http://localhost:8000/callback')]
     result = urllib2.urlopen('https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize', urllib.urlencode(post_data))
     content = result.read()
```

And after sending query I have httperror 403. I had already configured allowed_hosts in settings.py

Comment: please show your full code. Including settings.py. How are you using `settings.py` here

Comment: Well error 403 are not from django as i understand from your desription. Its from github. SOmething wrong with your query. ANyway for auth you can use this app: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth

Comment: Question is closed. Answer was that urllib2.urlopen send POST request if give it two arguments. Right: urllib2.urlopen('ex.ru?%s'%urllib.urlencode(data))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my expirence I know that working with urllib is rly hard, I would suggest to use `requests`
http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

You can easly send the get:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```